# SQL Query to extract latest 2 dates from a column

Tags: sql, teradatasql

A column consists of dates only. I need to extract the latest 2 dates from the table. What is the best way to do it?

Example: Values in a table having date column as `01-01-2021`, `01-02-2021`, `01-03-2021`
I would need `01-02-2021,01-03-2021` as my output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank()` (or `row_number()` if there are no dupicliates):

```
select t.*
from t
qualify rank() over (order by datecol desc) <= 2;
```

Note:  If you want distinct values, you could also use:

```
select distinct datecol
from t
order by datecol desc
limit 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order the column and then select the top X elements that you require

```
Select Top 2 col_Date
from MyTable
Order by col_Date DESC
```

The returned result would be a column
If you need to have a single string, there is a function that can help : STRING_SPLIT